# XSLT Node availability check

Tags: xslt

I want to check a variable have any node or any attribute.

```
XSL:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="testvar">
        <test><name first="Isaac" last="Sivakumar" middle="G"></name></test>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space($testvar)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$testvar"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'NO XML DATA AVAILABLE'"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to run the above code I am getting "NO XML DATA AVIALABLE." I need to check weather a variable has any node / any attributes irrespective of it has data or not.

Can you please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 your variable has a value of type "result tree fragment", you need to use an extension function to convert it to a node set first to be able to address nodes e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="testvar">
        <test><name first="Isaac" last="Sivakumar" middle="G"></name></test>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="exsl:node-set($testvar)/node()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$testvar"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'NO XML DATA AVAILABLE'"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using normalize-space or value-of does not make much sense given that your XML in the result tree fragment has all data in attributes and no text nodes with data.

And the test `test="exsl:node-set($testvar)/node()"` is just an example, it could of course use e.g. `test="exsl:node-set($testvar)//name"` to test for a specific element like a `name` element.

Given XSLT 1.0 but EXSLT common support it might be better to check with http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/object-type/index.html e.g.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="exsl:object-type($testvar) = 'string' and $testvar = ''">
    <xsl:value-of select="'NO XML DATA AVAILABLE'"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="exsl:object-type($testvar) = 'node-set'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$testvar"/>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Given XSLT 2.0 I would simply check e.g `if ($testvar instance of xs:string and $testvar = '') then 'NO XML DATA AVAILABLE' else $testvar`.

Comment: I am getting error when I pass empty variable.Error Description: XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

Comment: That error message citing an error code and the type `xs:string` sounds very much as if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor so I am confused why you tagged the question as xslt-1.0. Please tell us which XSLT processor exactly you use and show us exactly how you define the variable when you get the error. It looks like I overlooked that `<xsl:variable name="testvar"/>` in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 results in an empty string, so in that case the test is more complicated. However in XSLT 2.0 we could easily check now `if ($testvar instance of xs:string) then ... else ...`.

Comment: Thanks :) I am able to do with object-type. Thanks :)